# Lyx: no output PDF file produced

Tags: lyx

I'm getting the following error at .lyx file compilation.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.8.9)  9 AUG 2021 10:31
entering extended mode
**./novoficheiro2.tex
(novoficheiro2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latin9.def
File: latin9.def 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
)) (C:\Users\herme\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.st
y
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count190
\Gm@cntv=\count191
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count192
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen139
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen144
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@dimlist=\toks19
(C:\Users\herme\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen147
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen148
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count193
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count194
\leftroot@=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count196
\DOTSCASE@=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen149
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count198
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count199
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count266
\dspbrk@lvl=\count267
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count268
\column@=\count269
\maxfields@=\count270
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen150
\alignsep@=\dimen151
\tagshift@=\dimen152
\tagwidth@=\dimen153
\totwidth@=\dimen154
\lineht@=\dimen155
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
) (C:\Users\herme\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
) (C:\Users\herme\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/bigints\bigints.sty
Package: bigints 2010/02/15 Writing big integrals
Package bigints Info: This is Bigints by Merciadri Luca. on input line 5.
)

! LaTeX Error: File `Hermelino Nepomuceno.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.20 \input{Hermelino Nepomuceno}
                                 
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1791 strings out of 478868
 22760 string characters out of 2858480
 318797 words of memory out of 3000000
 19749 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 404193 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,0n,66p,232b,38s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I'm simply trying to compile a file with the general content "Test", that is save at directory "C:\Resume\novoficheiro1.lyx".

I have already unsuccessfully reinstalled the Miktex and also Lyx. Please, can someone help-me?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: I'm simply trying to compile a file with the content "Test".

Comment: Please post the Test-file, the way you did with the error messages (just press Edit of your post).

Comment: Please post the whole file. And I *strongly* suggest that there are no spaces in its name.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to post the "whole file". I put in the lyx file only the word "test" and its don't work.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the space in the file name?